# android runtime analysis tool

Tags: android, analytics

**What android runtime analysis tools are available for free?**

I am looking for a tool to help me analyze an algorithm that i have running in my android application. I have not been able to find one for free that works for android. I have found a few for java, but did not see any tutorials or how-to's on how to get them to work for android.

Here are some of the things i am wanting from this tool.

- execution time
- time spent in certain methods
- number of times a method is called
- loop iterations

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Profiling with Traceview and dmtracedump](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html)

Comment: +1: Didn't realize google provided this type of tool. Google just continues to amaze me. Thanks for the help. Will continue to wait for other answers and see what other people suggest. =)